# jquery datatable - how to get a value from a selected row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have a jQuery datatable and when I click a row, I want to get a value from one of the columns in the clicked row.

I have a function for the click event of the row so here I would like to get a column of that row.
I enter into this function when a row is clicked just fine.

Here is the view (not in its entirety) with the datatable and click event function.

Note: I build each rows href just fine and there I use row.columnname for the columns I need to build my query string. I get the href in my clicked function and I know I can just substring the PublishedSwitch out of the href. However, I will no longer be building that query string and hence it will not be part of the href. So I now need to get that row's publishedSwitch somehow from within the clicked function.

```
 @section Scripts
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Declare the datatable ViewModel.
    var gbngUpdateListVM;

    $(function () {
        gbngUpdateListVM = {
        dt: null,

        init: function () {
            dt = $('#gbngupdates-data-table').DataTable({
                "serverSide": true,
                "processing": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("GetGbngUpdatesForMaintList", "GbngUpdateMaint")",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "data": function (data) {
                        },
                    "error": function (error) {
                        // Set the error message from the key/value pair set in the controller: ErrorMessage = errorMessage.
                        $("#jsonErrorMessage").text(error.responseJSON.ErrorMessage);
                        // Show it.
                        $("#jsonErrorMessage").css("display", "block");
                    }
            },
                "columns": [
                    {
                          "title": "Actions",
                           "data": "GbngUpdateId",
                           "searchable": false,
                           "sortable": false,
                           "render": function (data, type, row, full, meta) {
                               return '<a href="@Url.Action("EditGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + data + '&publishedSwitchValue=' + row.PublishedSwitch + '&canBeSeenSwitch=' + row.CanBeSeenSwitch + '" class="editGbngUpdate">Edit</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("DetailsGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + data + '" class="detailsGbngUpdate">Details</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + data + '&publishedSwitchValue=' + row.PublishedSwitch + '&canBeSeenSwitch=' + row.CanBeSeenSwitch +'" class="deleteGbngUpdate">Delete</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "title": "Gbng Update Title", "data": "GbngUpdateTitle", "searchable": true },
                    { "title": "Published", "data": "PublishedSwitch", "searchable": true },
                    { "title": "Published Date", "data": "PublishedDateTime", "searchable": true },
                    { "title": "Alert Email Sent", "data": "AlertSentSwitch", "searchable": true },
                    { "title": "Can Be Seen", "data": "CanBeSeenSwitch", "searchable": true },
                ],
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
                });
            }
        }

        // Initialize the datatable.
        gbngUpdateListVM.init();
    });


    $('#gbngupdates-data-table').on("click", ".editGbngUpdate", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#successMessage').remove();
        $('#errorMessage').remove();

        // I can get the href element fine.
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

        // I want to get the publishedSwitch of this selected row. How?
        var publishedSwitch = ?????????;

        alert('publishedSwitch: ' + publishedSwitch); 

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#deleteGbngUpdateContainer').html(data);

            $('#deleteGbngUpdateModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is `publishedSwitch` ? Please show your html structure

Comment: `var yourData = table.row(this).data(); var publishedSwitch = yourData.publishedSwitch ;`

Comment: You got the value ?

Comment: Shree...no. In the console, I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined

Comment: Swati...PublishedSwich is one of the columns of the row in the datatable. It is defined there. In the href, I am able to reference it as I build the query string. However, I want to reference it in the clicked event of the row clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the clicked event function, I get that PublishedSwitch column value out of the clicked row by:

```
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the row clicked - this gets a row of the columns.
    //
    // It looks like this:
    //       Edit|Details|Delete   Test of yesterday   true        12/07/2020 20:02:40   false              true
    //
    // It's column headings are (these are for reference only and not part of the data below):
    //       Action                Title               Published   Published Date        Alert Email Sent   Can Be Seen
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var clickedRow = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');

    // From the clicked row, go threw the columns and extract out the value for - 'publishedSwitch'. It's value will be equal to 'true'.
    // - 0 based.
    var publishedSwitch = $(clickedRow).eq(2).text();
```